# When i run my script in regular run, it doesn't click the element

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

When i run my script in regular run, it doesn't click the element, when i run it in debug mode it clicked. i tried to put wait `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elem));`, and Thread.sleep(60000);

it doesn't work

```
    public void selectBrand(String brandName) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        waitElementUntilVisible(driver, brandList);
        WebElement allButton = driver.findElement(brandList);
        List<WebElement> getButton = allButton.findElements(By.className("srn-brand-list-item"));
        List<WebElement> getName = allButton.findElements(By.className("srn-brand-list-name"));
        for (WebElement brand : getName) {
            String name = brand.getText();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(brandName)) {

                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getButton.get(i));
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What web page is it? What element?

Comment: Is it the javascript executor click? I assume you've tried a normal click first?

Comment: Yes i tried getButton.get(i).click() and it work both in debug mode